# How many real solutions does the following polynomial systems has?

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

I am trying to understand the proof of theorem 2 in [the paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=7525284), which is related to the following system of equations:

$$b_1=s_1+s_1c_2-s_2c_1+s_1c_3-s_3c_1\\
b_2=s_2-s_1c_2+s_2c_1+s_2c_3-s_3c_2\\
b_3=s_3-s_1c_3+s_3c_1-s_2c_3+s_3c_2\\
0=s_1^2+c_1^2-1\\
0=s_2^2+c_2^2-1\\
0=s_3^2+c_3^2-1$$

In the paper (below equation $(41)$), it is stated that in the case $b_1 + b_2 + b_3 = 0$, there are 6 distinct real solutions. However, I tried Mathematica to obtain the solutions and here is what I obtained

```
(s1 == 0 && s2 == 0 && s3 == 0 && (c1 == -1 || c1 == 1) && (c2 == -1 || c2 == 1) && (c3 == -1 ||c3 == 1)) || 

(s1 == 0 && s3 == -s2 && s2 != 0 && c1 == -1 && (c2 == -Sqrt[1 - s2^2] || c2 == Sqrt[1 - s2^2]) && c3 == -c2) || 

((s2 == 0 || s2 == -s1) && s3 == -s1 - s2 && (c1 == -Sqrt[1 - s1^2] || c1 == Sqrt[1 - s1^2]) &&s1 != 0 && c2 == (-s1 - s2 + c1 s2)/s1 && c3 == -1 - c1 - c2)
```

Which doesn't seem to explain why there can only be $6$ solutions.

My thought on this is: I think the paper is trying to find all isolated real solutions, except for positive dimensional real solution sets.

But I am not sure.

Could anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: @GarethMa Thanks! So I need to find $s1$ according to (30), and then substitute the result of $s1$ into (35) (36) (37) and (18), am I right? It is weird that the paper does not give derivations. I think this is crucial for answering the question of number of solutions.

Comment: Thank you Gareth Ma for editing

Comment: The link to the paper is now down.

Comment: @user2661923 https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=7525284 This would work..